# htaccess RewriteCond does not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my webserver I would like to redirect all visits to specific file with two exceptions. If the URI is `mydomain.com/Folder1` or `mydomain/Folder2` (and anything behind that) they should work normally. I tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=www.mydomain.com/Folder1.* | www.mydomain.com/Folder2.*
RewriteRule ^.*$ www.mydomain.com/error.php [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But this rule does not work. Can someone please have a look on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match domain name using `REQUEST_URI`variable. You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(error\.php|Folder1|Folder2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /error.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for this. That works great but I have also two other RewriteRules in my htaccess file which are applied after this condition (I have added them to the question). Is it possible to neglect them if the first rule is applied or do I have to rewrite them?

Comment: That works wonderfull thank you for this! Can you also please explain shortly what `\s/+` does?

Comment: Since I'm using `THE_REQUEST` variable here and example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1` here `\s/+` matches space after `GET` and then 1 or more spaces at start of URI

Comment: Ah okay that's clever. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Sorry I have one more error. It comes to `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` if an URL is redirected by the first rule. error.php should lie in the root directory

Comment: What is the original URL you entered in browser?

Comment: For examle mydomain.com/abc. It redirects to mydomain.com/error.php but this file is not displayed instead it comes to the above error

Comment: Ah `error.php` should also be excluded, see updated answer.